# Can my boss send me home for personal reasons

Tags: professionalism, management, work-environment

I recently lost my grandpa and I was having a rough day and my mom texted me something about the funeral and I just about lost it I started crying all over the place my boss asked me what's wrong and I told him about my grandpa passing away and he said go home you will feel better. I told him I would be okay but he didn't care..... Was he right to send me home??

Comment: I think it was rather nice of him, don't you?  And yes, if you're emotionally wrought to the point that you're crying all over the place, you should go home.

Comment: I understand that but at the same time I hate losing money ( car payments)  I knew if stayed there I could of handled things ( my  lunch break was almost due) I could've collected myself and things would of been better but obviously things didn't go that way.

Comment: If your mood is affecting the rest of the staff, yes, they can and will tell you that you are not needed in the office right then. You _may_ be able to claim some of this as sick time, depending on the company's policies; ask your manager after you are back in control and back at work.

Comment: I think you should add the "without being paid" part in the question, as it makes quite a big difference. Telling someone to go home on their own dime is very different from sending them home on your own.

Comment: I have been sent home by my boss for looking bleak and sick, which was caused by personal problems not actual illness. My boss always saw this as a standard sick day. Are you really sure they want you to call in sick or take an unpaid day off?

Comment: @KarlieK My experience points to sending someone home on compassionate grounds would generally mean the time is paid.  In workplaces where it wouldn't be acceptable for a supervisor to give you paid time off for compassionate leave supervisors would be more likely to offer you an early break to get your composure back.  Talk to your supervisor when you get back to work out specifics.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

We are humans not machines because we have feelings. Had he not sent you home you couldn't have been productive. Moreover money comes and goes, you have your whole life to earn.

According to me he did what every man must do.

His actions are bound to improve his relations with employees and lead to a better environment at the office.

Answer (score 17):

This might sound callous, but it's disruptive to have someone crying in the office and sharing their personal drama with everyone else, or becoming a topic of conversation/pity/whatever.

So your boss may have felt compelled to send you home for the good of the rest of the office. It's the normal thing to do. It would be abnormal for him to have expected you to continue working for the rest of the day, both for decency reasons and business reasons.

Comment: That actually sounds logical ( when I think it all out)  Gossip is definitely something that happens at my workplace. I am almost embarrassed to face it all when I go back to work Wednesday. I know that since people do gossip they probably know all about my crying spell. I ..suppose I just have to hold my head up and shake things off when people mention things.

Answer (score -8):

He would have been right to send you home if your bouts of crying were  disruptive to the workplace and you weren't doing a stitch of work between your bouts of crying. And if your colleagues very naturally reach out to you to find out what's going on and offer you moral support and comfort, you end up not being the only one who is not doing a stitch of work during the workday. The blunt fact is that no amount of sympathy and empathy is going to change your personal situation let alone in anyway bring back the people you are grieving for.

I am not sure that crying about private matters in public spaces is such a great thing. It's a public spectacle for sure but it's no entertainment for the masses. Having said that, the workplace is definitely not an appropriate venue for crying your heart out. That you have a damn good reason to cry your heart out is besides the point.

Your boss said that you'd feel better if you were to cry at home. Left unsaid is that he'd feel better, too, about you crying at home and so would your colleagues.

I acknowledge that you were holding it together until your mother texted you - this means that you should really go home and stay home for a while because your grief is much stronger than you think and any little thing can trigger an uncontrollable explosion of grief on your part.

Comment: 90% of your answer could be packed into an comment. the other 10% has already been stated by someone else. And please úse an Quote when you Quote an part of the answer

Comment: @RaoulMensink - You obviously don't know that a paraphrase is an alternative for a quote. The other factor is that my answer is contemporary with the others and independently arrived at. I have no use for your second guessing as to how I should write my answers.

Comment: One: get your Facts right. Two: be nice.

Comment: Then why are you doing so? One: your answer came later and didnt add anything. Two: I am not second guessing you how you should write your answers, I merely gave you my opinion on why I downvoted it. As I feel you have the right to know why you are getting downvoted. Three: If I lectured you my comment wouldnt been that short. Four: be nice, nobody gains anything from being mean.